# What is known about the maximum of several independent standard normal random variables?

Tags: probability-distributions, expectation

[Bailey et al.](https://poseidon01.ssrn.com/delivery.php?ID=726071067021026023088029114127118028058084022041061078026026031075120029068088091010010097040106104063121089083100002113110103022084007077063112067123099098067092021005042071012105093098082025119113099075110024096103007102022108025106094085026000127&EXT=pdf&INDEX=TRUE), in the May 2014 issue of *Notices of the AMS*, show that, if $X_k\,$ ($k=1,...,n$) are independent standard normal random variables, then the expectation of their maximum is given approximately by
$$\mu(n):=\mathsf E \max\{X_1,...,X_n\}\approx(1-\gamma)\Phi^{-1}\!\!\left(1-\frac1n\right)+\gamma\Phi^{-1}\!\!\left(1-\frac1{n\mathrm e}\right)\!,$$
where $\mathrm e$ and $\gamma$ are respectively the Euler and Euler–Mascheroni constants, and $\Phi^{-1}$ is the inverse of the cumulative standard normal distribution function
$$\Phi:\Bbb R\to (0\,\pmb,\,1):x\mapsto\frac1{\surd(2\pi)}\int_{-\infty}^x\exp\frac{-t^2}2\,\mathrm dt.$$
While the above estimate for $\mu(n)$ holds asymptotically for large $n$, the cited paper provides no quantification of the error in approximation. Thus the following question arises:
$$\text{(1)$\;$Is an upper bound (in terms of $n$) known for the error in the above estimate of $\mu(n)$?}$$
More ambitiously, we might ask further whether there are known exact expressions for $\mu(n)$ and $\sigma^2(n):=\operatorname{var} \max\{X_1,...,X_n\}$.

Comment: There are no known exact expressions -- for a little detail, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/539914/225256

Comment: Since $\max(X_1,X_2)\le \max(X_1,\ldots,X_n)\le \sum\max(0,X_i)$, the expectations can be bounded as $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \le \mu_n \le \frac{n}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$$ How good would the bounds need to be for your purposes?

Comment: Concerning the right-hand side of your approximate equality, note that $(1-\gamma)\Phi^{-1}\!\!\left(1-\frac1n\right)+\gamma\Phi^{-1}\!\!\left(1-\frac1{n\mathrm e}\right)\sim\Phi^{-1}\!\!\left(1-\frac1n\right)$ as $n\to\infty$.